# Automatically create ASDF files for a Common Lisp project

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, asdf

Are there any libraries out there that do this? Playing around with Common Lisp it seems like this would be one of the most useful things to lower barrier of entry for newcomers.  ASDF seems mostly designed for deployment, not for rapid prototyping and development.  Following threads on comp.lang.lisp it seems like people agree that CL's package system is powerful, but lacks the ease of something like Python's dead simple module system.  It is FAIL in the sense that it's designed for power not usability.

Glad to know if I'm wrong. If I'm right, I'm stunned that noone has tried to build a Python module-like system on top of ASDF.

Answer (score 6):

[Zach Beane wrote](http://xach.livejournal.com/278047.html) how he nowadays starts new Common Lisp projects by using Quicklisp and Quickproject. This might be along the lines you want.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it's ready for prime time or whether it fits your requirements at all, but here's a link to [XCVB](http://common-lisp.net/project/xcvb/).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know. I mostly use ASDF for my in-development compilation needs. Once you notice that you'd benefiot from more than one source file, open <projectname>.asd, slap in a basic ASDF system definition template and start slapping filenames in. As and when you notice a cross-file dependency, update the dependency list.

But, then, I use the exact same method dealing with Makefiles (yes, I know there are automatic dependency checkers that can do it for you, but since I mostly code on my own, it's easier to just amend the Makefile/ASDF definition as I go).

In SBCL, there's a hook on REQUIRE that checks for ASDF systems, so you end up with something that is about as convenient as Python's import, but somehow I suspect that is not what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the answer you want, but clearly you have some idea of what you want in a module system. Have you considered creating one yourself? That is, taking your limited domain, your limited requirements, your environment and simply pounding out whatever abstractions will quickly make your life easier?

That's one of the key benefits of Lisp I'm sure you know, is that these simple abstractions and little tools are typically very easy to craft in Lisp.

I'm not suggesting solving everyone who has a problem with the package system or ASDF, I'm simply suggesting solving your own problem as you understand it, which is likely simpler and smaller than some more powerful larger scope.

Comment: This was the route I was considering, but it's nice to get the opinions and insights of the more experienced first ;)

Comment: I would not recommend rolling your own.  First, you are likely to get it wrong --- this is harder than it looks!  But more importantly, if you want to use *other people's* libraries, instead of working off by yourself and reinventing everything from scratch, ASDF makes available to you the world of open-source CL libraries.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Mudballs](http://mudballs.com/) now, too.

If you're looking for a piece of software to add this functionality to then it's a good bet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a command line tool that just uses bash to generate new common lisp project directory and file layouts, you may find one that I created for myself useful: [lispproject](https://github.com/analyticd/lispproject). If it doesn't match your needs, go ahead and fork it or the repo it gets it templates from to suit your needs: [lisp-project-template](https://github.com/analyticd/lisp-project-template). Look at the sh file in lispproject repo to see how the templates are used. Also, please note that you may need to adjust the calls to sed to fit your platform as I am using this on macOS. Alternative sed calls are in the main script but just commented out if you need them.

Comment: It's good to see more options, but I do not think that textual templates and bash/sed are inspiring choices.

Answer (score -4):

> it's designed for power not usability

that's how most Lisp gurus like it.

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for. Lisp is _both_, powerful _and_ usable. Not so much for ASDF